# Should I use "hold on," "hold out," or just "hold in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

> Tom **held (on/out)** long enough so Mary could have an orgasm.

What's the correct alternative and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heavily depends on the specific activities happening.

*Hold* means to be still or not move.

*Hold on* means to sustain some effort or position over time, or to wait until something.

*Hold out* - I like Google's definition - "resist or survive in dangerous or difficult circumstances."

If you have no other information other than your sentence, I would select "hold on", *hold out* won't work unless we know Mary is dangerous or difficult.